# How get the recent date out of 2 column in database using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 date column in Database Table for 2 dates:

```
CreatedDate
ModifiedDate
```

I need to get the most recent date out of both column using Linq in C#, I know how to get most recent in one Date not sure how add second Date?

This is for one date:

```
 var modifiedDate = DbContext.adminUser.OrderByDescending(x => x.ModifiedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then `modifiedDate.ModifiedDate` has the most recent Date.

Comment: `var modDate= DbContext.adminUser.Select(x => new {x.CreatedDate, x.ModfifiedDate}).OrderByDescending(x => x.ModifiedDate).ThenByDescending(x => xCreatedDate).First();`

Comment: This will return the both the modfieddate and createddate

Comment: @Alma I have added an answer, please check.

Comment: @jenzen thanks, worked!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are looking for [`Linq.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max) as follows:

```
var recentDate = DbContext.adminUser.Max(p=>p.ModifiedDate > p.CreatedDate ? p.ModifiedDate : p.CreatedDate);
```